# Python import within and outside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This is my situation. I have the following directory structure:

```
$ls -R                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      .:
driver.py  package

./package:
dependent.py  __init__.py  standalone.py
```

driver.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from package.dependent import add_n

if __name__=='__main__':
  print(add_n(2,2))
```

dependent.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from standalone import add_1

def add_n(x, n):
  for _ in range(n):
    x = add_1(x)
  return x
```

standalone.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def add_1(x):
  return x+1
```

Now depending on my use case, I want to run `dependent.py` directly or import it into `driver.py`. This is the problem I'm facing:

- Running `dependent.py` only works if there *is not* a dot when importing `add_1`. If there is one, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dependent.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .standalone import add_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.standalone'; '__main__' is not a package
```

- Running `package.py` only works if there *is* a dot when importing `add_1`. If there is not one, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from package.dependent import add_n
  File "/home/su0/scratch/package/dependent.py", line 3, in <module>
    from standalone import add_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'standalone'
```

I want both scenarios to work. This is because, in the real project, there are dependencies within the package that import other modules. And I want to be able to import it as a package as well. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `pwd` in this case?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. It's just some directory (a directory in my home).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to really [package](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the code and then use absolute imports in `dependent.py`. As a workaround you can however use one of the following options:

#### Extend the path in driver.py

Before the `import package.dependent` you can add the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('package')
```

Then use the undotted import statement in `dependent.py`. This works since now `package` is on the path to be searched for modules, including `standalone.py`.

#### Use conditional imports in dependent.py

You can modify the imports in `dependent.py` as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from standalone import ...
else:
    from .standalone import ...
```

Comment: Does the conditional import go at the very top to replace the original import statement?

Comment: Yes it needs to replace the original one. It can go anywhere but obviously has to be executed before you attempt to use the imported function. Anyway I'd rather use option 1 (package the code) or option 2 (extending `sys.path`); option 3 (conditional import) implies that `dependent.py` "knows" that it's going to be imported somewhere else, but then you could just put the code in a separate module anyway.